# Spring OAuth2 UserApprovalRequiredException thrown after successful login

Tags: java, xml, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have the following security xml for Spring (see below). I want to use OAuth2 to login a user through Facebook in this example. Most everything works - when the user tries to go to access a protected URL they are automatically redirected to the Facebook login page. When a successful login occurs Facebook redirects them to the appropriate URI `/authLogin` on my web-app. However a `UserApprovalRequiredException` is thrown but nothing handles it. I do not understand especially since the user did complete the login process and there is a `code` value in the redirect back to my app. I have included the stack trace below as well. Can anyone please help me understand how to remedy this?

**Security.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd">
 
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/application.properties" />
 
 <security:http pattern="/api" security="none"/>
 <security:http pattern="/geowave/**" security="none"/>
 <security:http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
     <!-- <security:http-basic /> -->
     <security:form-login default-target-url="/api"/>
     <security:anonymous enabled="false"/>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
     <security:custom-filter ref="oauth2ClientContextFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR"/> 
   </security:http>
   
 <!-- Login entry point -->
    <b:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
     <b:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/authLogin"/>
    </b:bean>
   
 <security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customAdmin">         
   </security:authentication-provider>
 </security:authentication-manager>
 
 <security:user-service id="customAdmin">
   <security:user name="geowave_username" password="geowave_password" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
 </security:user-service>
 
 <!--apply the oauth client context -->
    <b:bean id="oauth2ClientContextFilter"
  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter">
 </b:bean>
 <b:bean id="oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <b:constructor-arg name="defaultFilterProcessesUrl" value="/authLogin"/>
        <b:property name="restTemplate" ref="facebookRestTemplate"/>
    </b:bean>
    
 <b:bean id="facebook" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails">
     <b:property name="grantType" value="authorization_code"/>
     <b:property name="clientId" value="${oauth.client.id}"/>
        <b:property name="clientSecret" value="${oauth.client.secret}"/>
        <b:property name="authenticationScheme" value="query"/>
        <b:property name="accessTokenUri" value="${oauth.accessTokenUri}"/>
        <b:property name="userAuthorizationUri" value="${oauth.userAuthorizationUri}"/>    
        <b:property name="useCurrentUri" value="false"/>
        <b:property name="preEstablishedRedirectUri" value="${oauth.redirect.url}"/>
        <b:property name="tokenName" value="${oauth.tokenName}"/>
        <b:property name="scope" value="${oauth.authScope}"/>
        <b:property name="clientAuthenticationScheme" value="form"/>
 </b:bean>
 
 <b:bean id="facebookRestTemplate" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate" scope="session">
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
        <b:constructor-arg name="resource" ref="facebook"/>
        <b:property name="messageConverters">
            <b:list>
                <b:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                    <b:property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                        <b:list>
                            <b:bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                                <!--facebook sends its json as text/javascript for some reason -->
                                <b:constructor-arg value="text" />
                                <b:constructor-arg value="javascript" />
                            </b:bean>
                            <b:bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                                <b:constructor-arg value="application" />
                                <b:constructor-arg value="json" />
                            </b:bean>
                        </b:list>
                    </b:property>
                </b:bean>
            </b:list>
        </b:property>
    </b:bean>
</b:beans>
```

**Stack Trace**

```html
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserApprovalRequiredException
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.getUserApprovalSignal(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:376)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAuthorizationCode(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:161)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:207)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:148)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:121)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ca6dc720.invoke(<generated>)
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3a151063.getAccessToken(<generated>)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:105)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing my bean definition for the `oauth2ClientContextFilter` with the `oauth:client` element defined in the Spring OAuth2 xsd. I also ended up using `oauth:resource` and `oauth:rest-template` to ensure Spring auto-configured the beans with the appropriate scopes (session, request, etc). This way the appropriate context data made its way through the filter chain as expected.